# Can't find error from atmega128 C code

Tags: c, timer, atmel, atmelstudio

This is 3 digit timer's code in ATMEGA 128 microcontroller. If you push button which connected to port D, timer will start. However If you press it for while, timer will reset. In proteus simulation microcontroller counts to only 1 after i press button. From that on nothing happens (Display is still "001")

```
#define F_CPU   4000000UL
#include<avr/io.h>
#include<avr/delay.h>
int x;

int button_check(int x)
{   DDRD = 0x00;
    if(PIND==0xFF)
    {
        _delay_ms(200);
        if(PIND==0xFF)
        {   x=1;}
        else
        {   x=0;}
    }
    else
    { x=x;}
    return x;
}

int main(void)
{
    int a,b,c;
    DDRA = 0xFF;
    DDRB = 0xFF;
    DDRC = 0xFF;
    x=1;
    while(1)
    {   
        a=0;
        b=0;
        c=0;

        while(button_check(x)==0) //starting condition
        {  _delay_ms(200);
            if(a==9)
            { a=0;
                if(b==9)
                {  b=0;
                    if(c==9)
                    {  c=0;}
                    else
                    {  c=c+1;}
                }
                else
                {   b=b+1;}
            }
            else
            {   a=a+1;}
            PORTA = a;
            PORTB = b;
            PORTC = c;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is the idea behind this `x=x;`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value from x never changes in main().

You want

```
while((x=button_check(x))==0)
```

Comment: It works. But I still don't know why? Since x is global variable, it's value must change globally, isn't it? And much obliged for your kindness

Comment: What you see is the so-called "shadowing" of a variable. You have a global variable called "x". But you have also a function parameter called x in button_check(). The compiler will assume that you always mean the local function parameter, when you talk about x within button_check(). And x is actually a copy of the global variable on the local function stack, as you have _passed_ it as copy to the function. If you change the prototype to `int button_check(int y)`, the compiler would be able to see that you want to change the global x, because there is no other x.